# nrf24l01 transceiver on altera board de2-115

Tags: led, wireless, intel-fpga, transceiver, nrf24l01

I'm trying to use the nrf24l01 transceiver on altera board de2-115. I would like to send a signal from the altera board using this spi module to another spi module and use the spi module on the receiving side to turn on an LED and a vibrating motor. Does anyone know if this board works with this spi module and how ?

Comment: Exactly the same comment as to [this question of 27min ago](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274335/verilog-de2-115) (are you two on the same lab/course/assignment?): *Sorry, this is a little too broad. Could you come up with a sketch of any design that you might want to discuss?*

Comment: Plus, you did not even ask a question!

Comment: I want to know if the spi module is applicable with the altera board and no we are not. My project is completely different

Comment: That's actually question, and you should [edit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/274342/edit) your question to include that! But, after your research you know that both the nrf chip and the FPGA "speak" SPI; you probably already know how SPI works and are perfectly capable of searching for SPI examples for that FPGA – I wonder whether you can *specify* that question "will it work?" further to say why you think it might *not work*.You've got a legitimate question,but,you don't sound like the type that needs to verify every single design step with someone else, why do you do that here?

Comment: I don't have experience with this board, it's the first time I work on it and I looked for the way to send signals from it through the spi transceiver but I couldn't find anything online for it so I figured I should ask here if someone knows if this is going to work and how can I do it ?

Comment: "does anyone know if and how" isn't really a great question, still – I mean, really, googling for "Altera FPGA SPI example" **does** lead to a lot of results, including a few application notes from Altera/Intel. It's really not that likely that someone has used **exactly** your combination of devices, so I really think it would be worth your time first looking deeper into how SPI on your FPGA can be done, and then asking a more specific question.

Comment: @Lose'CKi Did you ever work with PLDs (CPLDs, GALs, FPGAs, ...) before or do you only have microcontroller experience?

Comment: only micro controller experience

Comment: If that's the case, you could "cheat", and program the FPGA to be a microprocessor, and program the SPI code in C. Otherwise, the solution will take a large amount of learning about digital logic.

Comment: @Pigrew very true! Also, whatever you do with SPI will probably require something that acts very much like a software programmable state machine – also known as processor.

Answer (score 1):

The DE2-115 FPGA board does not have any hardware dedicated to SPI (actually, it does for loading its configuration from flash, but not for other uses), so the SPI logic must be synthesized using the FPGA fabric.

There are a few different options as to how the SPI logic will interface with other system components. In the end, all choices end up using GPIO for output. One would select four pins to use (clk, mosi, miso, and cs) and assign your module's ports to those pins.

But, there are a few different choices you have for how to interface your controlling logic with the SPI core:

1. Use a "normal" verilog module
2. Use a SPI component (Altera provides one for their Avalon bus architecture)
3. Instantiate a CPU (such as NIOS) and use bit-banging to construct the SPI signals using a 4-bit "conduit".

If you're using an Avalon bus already, I'd suggest that method #2 would be the simplest. But, if you are not using SoC design techniques, you may want to investigate writing (or buying or downloading) a pre-written SPI-interface module.